# C++ displaying the wrong object

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++ and I am trying to create 2 classes that stores Movie for each Day. 
For example, there are 2 movies on saturday. One of the movie is Batman and the other is Spiderman. So the object `Day saturday` should store 2 different movies. However, the problem is when I tried to display the object stored in saturday with the function `showAllMovies()` within the class `Day`, it showed the last movie only. Any idea what I have done wrong?

EDIT: I can only use these libraries since my assignment won't allow me to use other libraries.

```
<iostream>, <iomanip>, <fstream>, <cmath>
```

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

class Movie {
private:
    char* name;
public:
    void setName(char* n) {
        name = n;
    }
    char* getName() {
        return name;
    }
};

class Day {
private:
    int movieCount = 0;
    Movie movie[20];
public:
    void addMovie(Movie p) {
        movie[movieCount] = p;
        movieCount++;
    }
    void showAllMovies() {
        for (int i = 0;i < movieCount;i++) {
            cout << "Index: " << i << ", Name: " << movie[i].getName() << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Day saturday;
    int numOfMovies = 0;

    cout << "Input the number of Movies: " << endl;
    cin >> numOfMovies;

    cout << "Input the name of Movie: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0;i < numOfMovies;i++) {
        char movieName[10];
        //Get input
        cin >> movieName;
        Movie m;
        m.setName(movieName);
        saturday.addMovie(m);

    }

    //Show all the name of movies
    cout << "All movies on saturday: " << endl;
    saturday.showAllMovies();

    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**
2
Batman
Spiderman

**Output:**
[image]

I am expecting to get something like

```
All movies on saturday:
Index: 0, Name: Batman
Index: 1, Name: Spiderman
```

**Thanks to everyone helping me out. The Solution is to change**

```
char movieName[10];
```

to

```
char *movieName = new char[10];
```

Comment: Why you do not use std::vector to store your Movie objects and std::string to store Movie name?

Comment: Not related to your question, but use "std::string name;" instead of "char* name;"

Comment: You store a pointer to the name, and they all point to the same `char movieName[10];`. Use a `std::string` member instead.

Comment: What did you discover [when debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0;i < numOfMovies;i++) {
        char movieName[10];
        //Get input
        cin >> movieName;
        Movie m;
        m.setName(movieName);
        saturday.addMovie(m);

    }
```

when you call `setName` internally you make `name` (which is field of `Movie` object) point to `movieName` - however, `movieName` dies on the next iteration of the for loop due to scope.

The last instance of `movieName` should also not be accessed after the loop ends.

Comment: Any way I can solve it without using any other libraries like strings or vector?

Comment: @BlueFishy Instead of doing char `movieName[10]` create `creatMovieName` on the heap e.g. using `new`. then point to that. in that case it will not die when loop ends. But you will need to free it properly later on.

Comment: @BlueFishy Make a copy of the string using `strdup()`.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Thanks a lot! Solved the problem :)